# Jeep won't start

Tags: starting, jeep, repair

It was started and running. I stopped at the store turned it off went inside was in there for a little while came out turned the key and it didn't have the spring back when you normally start the Jeep. It move forward and stays there no start no clicking nothing. All the lights come on but won't start what could it be and how do I get it to start so I can drive it?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your ignition switch is either broken or it has come loose from its mount.

If it is simply loose: Put the key in and turn it in the opposite direction, counterclockwise. Wiggle and jiggle the key and the entire switch to see if you can get it to return to its original position. Then, with the fingers of your left hand, hold the bezel or ring or any part of the face of the ignition switch so it doesn't turn, and turn the key with your right hand to start the Jeep.

If there's a manual transmission, don't forget to depress the clutch when you try to start -- with all the finger manipulations, you may forget.

If the ignition switch is actually broken internally, there's not much you can do without tools and replacement parts. A mobile locksmith may be able to help, but you may have to have the Jeep towed to a repair shop.